# Will casting Dispel Magic on one construct from Animate Objects end the animation of all the constructs?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, animated-objects

[*Animate objects*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/animate-objects) states a condition for ending the animation and control of the constructs:

> Each target animates and becomes a creature under your control until the spell ends or until reduced to 0 hit points.

[*Dispel magic*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dispel-magic) says:

> Choose one creature, object, or magical effect within range. Any spell of 3rd level or lower on the target ends. For each spell of 4th level or higher on the target, make an ability check using your spellcasting ability. The DC equals 10 + the spell's level. On a successful check, the spell ends.

If a character casts *dispel magic* on one of ten tiny constructs animated by *animate objects*, does that end the *animate objects* spell, and thereby end the animation of the other 9 constructs as well?

Comment: Related on [Can dispel magic end a conjure animals spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/90140/can-dispel-magic-end-a-conjure-animals-spell)

Comment: Related on [What happens when you target dispel magic at a summoned creature?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/79515/what-happens-when-you-target-dispel-magic-at-a-summoned-creature)

Comment: Related on [Can you Dispel animated dead?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/130561/can-you-dispel-animated-dead)

Comment: @enkryptor The major difference there is that animate dead has an instantaneous duration.  So there is no spell to dispel.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Dispel Magic would work on One Construct At a Time

Dispel Magic's text has makes a crucial distinction:

> Choose one creature, object, or magical effect within range. Any spell of 3rd level or lower **on the target** ends. (PHB p. 234, bold added)

The later description of higher level spells is subject to the same restriction: specifically, it ends spells *on a target,* but may not end the entire spell.

Jeremy Crawford has [issued some guidance](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/732796836004691968) on this matter:

> Dispel magic ends spells on a target, not on every target affected by the same spell.

And has [further clarified elsewhere](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/1022951482604367875):

> When you use dispel magic to target a magical effect within range, you're choosing a discrete effect that you're aware of, often one created by a spell. If a spell has put an ongoing effect on multiple creatures, each of those creatures bears a discrete, targetable effect.

As such, a casting of Dispel Magic on a construct of Animate Objects would cause that object to become inanimate, but would not end the spell's effects on other targets.

Comment: Another good reason to use Tiny objects (as if you needed more.)

Comment: Yup. I mean, If you were willing to spend a 3rd level spell slot to end this spell, Fireball (on the small/tiny objects) or magic missile (on the caster) would usually also work. But there can be extenuating circumstances which make those spells inconvenient/unavailable.

Comment: This is also similar to spells that affect multiple targets and give each target a saving throw to end the effect, such as *slow*. If one target makes their save and ends the effect on themselves, the spell continues for other affected targets.

Comment: True. Although in the case of *slow* (and some other spells), the text states that if the target succeeds on the saving throw "the effect ends *for it*." The wording of *Dispel Magic* is definitely more ambiguous, so I understand why the question originally came up.

Comment: Well, spending a 3rd level to *try* and end it. It's a 5th level spell, so you'd still need to make the DC15 ability check. Unless you upcast it as a 5th. But that's plain silly.